# Why does "using namespace xxx" not take effect on template functions?

Tags: c++, namespaces

```
namespace ns1
{
    template <class T>
    void f(T)
    {
        cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
    }
};

using namespace ns1;

namespace ns2
{
    void f(int)
    {
        cout << "int" << endl;
    }

    void test()
    {
        f(vector<int>()); // Error! 
        // Why not call ns1::f<vector<int>>(vector<int>()); ???
    }
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has nothing to do with templates, but without name lookup.

This is what the standard says in 3.4/1 (name lookup) :

> Name lookup shall find an unambiguous
>   declaration for the name (see 10.2).
>   Name lookup may associate more than
>   one declaration with a name if it
>   finds the name to be a function name;
>   the declarations are said to form a
>   set of overloaded functions (13.1).
>   Overload resolution (13.3) takes place
>   after name lookup has succeeded. The
>   access rules (clause 11) are
>   considered only once name lookup and
>   function overload resolution (if
>   applicable) have succeeded.

And in 3.4.1 (unqualified name lookup) :

> **name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name**

In your case, `f` is an unqualified name. It is searched in the immediate scope, and in namespace `ns2` **where a declaration is found**. Name lookup ends here, and overload resolution comes into play : there is no overload in the candidate set which matches the argument type `std::vector<int>`, so the program is ill-formed.

Comment: thank you very much. Your answers are always quick and correct.

Answer (score 2):

Because when you're inside a namespace (ns2) it takes precedence over any others if names are unqualified.

Answer (score 2):

ns2 will take priority as that is the namespace you are currently in. Why should the compiler think that you really meant ns1::f() ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
namespace ns1
{
    template <class T>
    void f(T)
    {
        cout << typeid(T).name() << endl;
    }
};



namespace ns2
{
    using ns1::f;
    void f(int)
    {
        cout << "int" << endl;
    }

    void test()
    {
        f(vector<int>()); // Error! 
        // Why not call ns1::f<vector<int>>(vector<int>()); ???
    }
};
```